# Como aumentar o tamanho do gráfico de correlação feito no seaborn?

Tags: python

Como tem 16 variáveis fica pouco visível, gostaria que ficasse maior para melhor visualização.

```py
correlation = df.corr()  
correlation  
plot = sns.heatmap(correlation, annot = True, fmt=".1f", linewidths=.1)  
plot
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Esse tópico em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31594549/how-to-change-the-figure-size-of-a-seaborn-axes-or-figure-level-plot) mostra várias maneiras diferentes de aumentar o tamanho de um gráfico. Voce pode aumentar a resolução ("dpi", dots per inch, ou pontos por polegada) com o método `.fig.set_dpi`:

```
correlation = df.corr()
correlation
plot = sns.heatmap(correlation, annot = True, fmt=".1f", linewidths=.1)
plot.fig.set_dpi(100)
plot
```